# Use of "ante" to refer to previous pages in an English text

Tags: prepositions, latin, citation

At work I have seen "ante" being used for referring to previous pages of notes written by staff. For instance, when one has to refer to something on previous note, he/she would write, "Refer observation of Mr. XYZ on noting page 1 ante". I have searched on the web but couldn't find anything concrete. At least nothing that pertains to English language. Is it something conventional or erratic usage?

Comment: *ante* is a Latin preposition and prefix meaning *before*

Comment: -ante is also a participial suffix in Italian and French.  OP assumes that the "staff" are competent users of English.  Quoted context would help determine if this is so.

Comment: @Rob_Ster yes, the staff includes well read officers. Our organization is a government board. For instance, when one has to refer to something on previous note, he/she would write, "Refer observation of Mr. XYZ on noting page 1 ante". My guess is that at some point in history someone used it as a prefix and they adopted it wrongly.

Comment: Based on that example, it looks like they are not using it as a suffix, but as a postposition. It says "page 1 ante" not "page 1-ante" or "page 1ante."

Comment: @sumelic thanks for the clarification, but will it mean the same if it is used as postposition instead of being a prefix? The word ante is defined as _a stake put up by a player in poker_ when used as a noun and _pay an amount of money in advance_ when used as a verb.

Comment: @Nix - The context makes it clearer.  The usage is probably archaic in the mainstream, and most likely derives from Latin grammar and usage ironed onto a bed of Victorian English,  Similar fossils include the abbreviation "Inst.," which means "in the current month."

Comment: All right. Thank you for the clarification folks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, *ante* is a [citation signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_signal).  Citation signals are used in legal writing to indicate how a cited work relates to the given document.

The linked Wikipedia article does not mention *ante* specifically, but does give examples of citations that make use of it, for example under *contra* we see:

> Example: *Contra, ante*, at 690-691.

Which is a short-hand to indicate that the previously cited reference, on pages 690 and 691, gives information contrary to the argument being written.

The [legal dictionary](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Ante) at Free Dictionary gives a definition for *ante*, and notes it is synonymous to *supra*, as does [Oxford Reference](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780195369380.001.0001/acref-9780195369380-e-219), though one needs a subscription to read more than:

> is sometimes used as a citation signal in the same manner as *supra* to indicate that ...

The citation signal *supra* is discussed at Wikipedia with multiple examples.

As discussed in comments, the origin is the Latin *ante*, meaning *before*.

Comment: Thank you, I'm familiar with the citation signal supra. So would it be safe to assume that Rob_Ster is right in suggesting that _...the usage is probably archaic in the mainstream, and most likely derives from Latin grammar and usage ironed onto a bed of Victorian English..._" but it is in fact correct usage of the word grammatically?

Answer (score 0):

"Ante" is a Latin word meaning "before" in English e.g. "ante mortem" means "before death." On similar principle, we say "post mortem" which mean "after death" in English.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  A good answer will cite the sources for the answer. It would be well to rewrite your answer citing sources. Thanks